# Keyboard notifications not firing on device

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6

There is no problem when running on the simulator, but the notifications are not posting on the devices (iPad 3 and Mini both running iOS 6).  If I post the notification myself, the handler gets called.  I was wondering if any of you guys have run into this and have any ideas.

Here is the code setting up the handlers:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(iPadEditSetTitleHandleKeyboardDidShowNotification:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(iPadEditSetTitleHandleKeyboardWillShowNotification:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(iPadEditSetTitleHandleKeyboardWillHideNotification:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

And the definitions of the handlers themselves:

```
- (void)iPadEditSetTitleHandleKeyboardWillHideNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
- (void)iPadEditSetTitleHandleKeyboardWillShowNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
- (void)iPadEditSetTitleHandleKeyboardDidShowNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
```

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

Started a new project to get everything out of the way here is the view controller, all of it.

```
//
//  DWViewController.m
//  KeyboatdTest
//
//  Created by Dan Wesnor on 12/3/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Dan Wesnor. All rights reserved.
//

#import "DWViewController.h"

@interface DWViewController ()

@end

@implementation DWViewController


- (void)handleKeyboardNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"%@", notification.name);
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleKeyboardNotification:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleKeyboardNotification:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleKeyboardNotification:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@end
```

The storyboard contains a single text field.  Everything else is the standard single-view app template.

Still no joy.  Works as it should in the simulator, but not on the iPad itself.  Could it be something to do with provisioning or something outside of the code itself?

Comment: Is it not working on any device or not working on all devices you have?

Comment: Just checked and it works fine on iPhone.  Only fails to fire on all my iPads.

Comment: You can set yourself as an observer for nil, this will give you all observations. You can use that to sanity check if the notifications are firing or not. [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(someselector:) name:nil object:nil]; then just log the notifcation name.

Comment: Where did you add this code ?

Comment: are you doing something where there are one or two viewcontrollers handling subviews of another view controller on ipad? I think there's more to it that just adding your handlers and definitions. Will need more details about how your iPad view controller is different from iPhone's

Comment: Bergasms - good to know, but I'm sure I'd catch the notifications if they were firing.  Will try it anyway.

Comment: imthi - Everywhere in the view controller.

Comment: calvinBhai - The app has only 1 view controller, same for iPad and iPhone.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a nice undocumented behavior.

Those 3 notifications are not fired when the keyboard is split.  But, it appears that attaching UITextField.inputAccessoryView before they would usually fire, they fire even if the keyboard is split.  So attach the accessory view after receiving UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification and the other three will fire as normal.